# ffmpeg Real-time buffer issue [rtbufsize parameter]

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

Im trying to Stream the Audio and Video over the Network using this command

```
  -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio=""virtual-audio-capturer"" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency-pix_fmt yuv422p -f mpegts udp://{IpAddress}:1234
```

but after 5 minutes of perfect quality streaming im getting this Error Message and the Stream suddenly stopps streaming.

[image]

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Images of text is discouraged: copy and paste is better. Also, Stack Overflow is only for programming questions. Please ask at [su] if you have more `ffmpeg` cli usage questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a larger buffer for the audio

```
-f gdigrab -framerate 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -rtbufsize 15M -i audio=""virtual-audio-capturer"" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv422p -f mpegts udp://{IpAddress}:1234
```